# Is there any utility that can drop me into a Intel ME Minix shell?

Tags: shell, security, intel, minix

I see a lot of talk about [Intel -3 ring mode](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/09/26/intel_management_engine_exploit/) running Minix. Is there any easy C program I can compile, or utility I can run that will drop me into a -3 ring mode Minix shell?

Comment: Tongue in cheek answer: there probably is, but you can’t have it. (The recent [proof-of-concept](https://blackhat.com/eu-17/briefings.html#how-to-hack-a-turned-off-computer-or-running-unsigned-code-in-intel-management-engine) involves modifying the firmware.)

Comment: Tthis probably won't allow you to pop a shell, but there's a [linux driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/misc-devices/mei/mei.txt) for the HECI (the communication bus used for ME). Also [here](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-17/materials/eu-17-Goryachy-How-To-Hack-A-Turned-Off-Computer-Or-Running-Unsigned-Code-In-Intel-Management-Engine.pdf) is a very interesting Blackhat presentation about the topic